# I get "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". How do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, typeerror

I am working on some code that will take the data from OpenWeatherMap.org and displays the weather. Here's what I have so far:

```
import requests, json

apikey = "7cb9becaea566cc27d69991c345fa129"
base = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?"
lat = "censored"
lon = "censored"
compbase = f"{base}lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude=current,minutely,hourly&appid={apikey}"
print(compbase)
resp = requests.get(compbase)
x = resp.json()
daily = x["daily"]
temp = daily["temp"]
des = daily["weather"]
currtemp = temp["morn"]
currtemp = str(round(float(1.8)*(currtemp - 273) + 32, 1))
currpres = day["pressure"]
currpres = str(round(currpres/3386, 1))
currhum = day["humidity"]
feelslike = day["feels_like"]
feelslike = str(round(float(1.8)*(feelslike - 273) + 32, 1))
winds = str(round(float(y["wind_speed"]), 1))
weatherdes = str(des["description"])
if "alerts" in x:
    alerts = x["alerts"]
    aldes = alerts["description"]
    print()
    print("ALERT!!!!")
    print()
    print(f"Your WeatherWatcher program has been interuppted by {alerts['sender_name']}. Please pay attention closely.")
    print()
    print(str(aldes))
print()
print(f"It is currently {currtemp} degrees Fahrenheit outside.")
print()
print(f"It feels like {feelslike} degrees Fahrenheit outside.")
print()
print(f"The wind is blowing at {winds} MPH.")
print()
print(f"The pressure is at {currpres} inhg.")
print()
print(f"The humidity is at %{currhum}.")
print()
print(f"OpenWeatherMap describes this weather as {weatherdes}.")
print()
print("This data was brought to you by WeatherWatcher.")
```

(Sorry, kinda long.)

But when I run it, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ron83\OneDrive\Documents\weather.py", line 12, in <module>
    temp = daily["temp"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What did I do wrong? I know I didn't make it a string.

Comment: Apparently, `daily` is a list. Indexing lists with strings is not possible, so an error is raised

Comment: Why do you expect `daily["temp"]` to work? Perhaps you need to convert it into a dictionary before you treat it as a dictionary. In any event, it would probably help to put `print(x)` and `print(daily)` in the lines right before the error to see what you are dealing with. You are apparently making some assumptions about them which are not true.

Comment: This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: first check what you have in variable `print( daily )` and `print( len(daily) )`. Probably you have values for many days and you have to use `daily[0]["temp"]` to get temperature for first day, And `daily[1]["temp"]` for second day, etc. OR you should use `for`-loop to display values for all days on this list `for day in daily: print( day["temp"] )`

Comment: Thanks everyone! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is: API returns values for 8 days and you have to use index `[0]` to get value for today (or `[1]` for tomorrow, `[2]` for day after tomorrow, etc.)

```
day = daily[0]

temp      = day["temp"]
des       = day["weather"]
currpres  = day["pressure"]
currhum   = day["humidity"]
feelslike = day["feels_like"]
```

instead of

```
day = daily["temp"]
```

---

Becasause data are more complex so there are other mistakes

It needs `[0]` in `weather

```
des = day["weather"][0]
```

it needs `['day']` in `feels_like`

```
feelslike = day["feels_like"]
```

Simply use `print()` to see what you have in variables

---

Working code:

```
import requests, json

apikey = "7cb9becaea566cc27d69991c345fa129"
base = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?"
lat = "52"
lon = "10"
compbase = f"{base}lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude=current,minutely,hourly&appid={apikey}"
print(compbase)

resp = requests.get(compbase)
data = resp.json()
daily = data["daily"]

#print("[DEGUB] daily:", daily)
#print("[DEGUB] len(daily):", len(daily))
day = daily[0]   # needs [0]

temp = day["temp"]

#print('[DEGUB] day["weather"]:', day["weather"])
des = day["weather"][0]   # needs [0]

currtemp = temp["morn"]
currtemp = str(round(float(1.8)*(currtemp - 273) + 32, 1))
currpres = day["pressure"]
currpres = str(round(currpres/3386, 1))
currhum = day["humidity"]

#print('[DEGUB] day["feels_like"]:', day["feels_like"])
feelslike = day["feels_like"]['day']   # needs ["day"]

feelslike = str(round(float(1.8)*(feelslike - 273) + 32, 1))
winds = str(round(float(day["wind_speed"]), 1))
weatherdes = des["description"]

if "alerts" in data:
    #print('[DEGUB] data["alerts"]:', data["alerts"])
    alerts = data["alerts"][0]   # needs [0]
    aldes = alerts["description"]
    print()
    print("ALERT!!!!")
    print()
    print(f"Your WeatherWatcher program has been interuppted by {alerts['sender_name']}. Please pay attention closely.")
    print()
    print(str(aldes))
print()
print(f"It is currently {currtemp} degrees Fahrenheit outside.")
print()
print(f"It feels like {feelslike} degrees Fahrenheit outside.")
print()
print(f"The wind is blowing at {winds} MPH.")
print()
print(f"The pressure is at {currpres} inhg.")
print()
print(f"The humidity is at %{currhum}.")
print()
print(f"OpenWeatherMap describes this weather as {weatherdes}.")
print()
print("This data was brought to you by WeatherWatcher.")
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much!